Firebase security rule to limit access based on array intersection
Suppose I have a Firestore Database with a collection applications which has a document that has this structure:
apartmentPreferenceId: string
createdAt: string
matchedTenantProfileIds: string[]
propertyId: string
status: string
userId: string

I would like to add an access rule that would allow users to retrieve only the applications records that either belong to them OR where there is an intersection between the matchedTenantProfileIds and all the ids of tenantPreferences added by the userId of the current user.
The structure of the tenantPreferences is:
createdAt: string
profileName: string
userId: string

I'm trying to use this rule
  // Allow users to create and manage applications
    match /applications/{applicationId} {
      
      allow read: if request.auth != null && (
        resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid ||
         [what to put here?]
      );
           
      allow list: if request.auth != null && (
        resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid ||
        [what to put here?]
      );
      
    }

But I'm at a loss for how I can limit the access based on the condition I describe above:  the [what to put here?] field.
Maybe somebody can help me?
UPDATE:
Here's the query I'm using on my backend:
    const applicationsQuery = query(
          collection(db, 'applications'),
          where('matchedTenantProfileIds', 'array-contains', id)
    );

    const applicationsSnapshot = await getDocs(applicationsQuery);
    const matchedApplicationsData = applicationsSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() } as Application));


I wanted to use this function ownsTenantProfile to add this into the rules to ensure that applications are only shown to the people who created them and also the landlords who own the tenantProfiles listed in the array matchedTenantProfileIds
 function ownsTenantProfile(profileId) {
      let profile = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/tenantPreferences/$(profileId)).data;
      return profile != null && profile.userId == request.auth.uid;
    }

But it doesn't seem to work because it blocks the user from seeing even the applications that satisfy the rule...

Note: Firebase security rules don't filter the data on their own. Instead they simply ensure that the client only tries to access data they are permitted to. So, did you already write the query you want to execute against the data, without securing it with rules? If so, can you edit the question to include that?

Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

@FrankvanPuffelen I wrote the query but I wanted to limit access via the rules for added security. It's not possible?

@AlexMamo edited the question and clarified as requested

Your query limits the documents it requests with this condition:
where('matchedTenantProfileIds', 'array-contains', id)

To secure this query (read the linked docs please), you'll need to check this same condition in the security rules.
I'm not sure what id is in your code, but if that's for example the UID of the current user, you should be able to secure it with a condition like this:
request.auth.uid in resource.data.matchedTenantProfileIds

In addition to the documentation guides I linked above, I recommend also keeping the reference documentation for security rules handy.

Thank you, I'll try it out! So just to understand the logic of those rules: in fact, the where queries are only possible when they are explicitly allowed by the rules?

It is possible to only allow specific queries, yes. You have to essentially replicate the conditions of your query in the checks in your rules, as I did here. The links I included in my answer contain more examples of how to do that.
